# Mathematica crashes when plotting over region

Tags: plotting, regions, crash

Mathematica (12.0.0 or 12.3.0) crashes and kernel quits on my computer (Win 10) when I try the simple exercise of plotting over a region (taken from this Wolfram [page](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/visualization--labels-scales-exclusions/plot-over-regions.html?product=mathematica)):

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, y} \[Element] 
Disk[{0, 0}, 1], ImageSize -> 
500, 
PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

A similar problem happens when I work with StreamPlot over a Disk region.

Any advice on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: `Plot3D[x y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 500, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], PlotPoints -> 80,
  PlotTheme -> "Web"]`

Comment: @cvgmt many thanks. Your method works! Any ideas on why the original code didn't work? I even upgraded to version 12.3 but it still doesn't like it

Answer (score 1):

works in 12.3.1

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1], ImageSize -> 500, PlotTheme -> "Web"]
```

[image]